# Short Story about chess playing supercomputers

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Here's what I remember of the plot:

> Russia and the US both build a supercomputer that's designed to play chess. They meet in a highly publicized event where the two computers will play each other.
>
> They flip to see who goes first, and the US wins. Everyone watches with bated breath as the US computer makes its first move. And then it's Russia's first turn, and the computer... *concedes*.

The implication is that the Russian computer solved all possible moves, and quit because it realized it couldn't win going second if the US computer played perfectly.

I believe this was in a short story, probably in some sort of anthology book.  I read it 10-15 years ago, and it could be much older than that - it had a very "cold war" feel.  It was in English.

Comment: Are you sure of the detail that the chess players were supercomputers? As opposed to robot avatars controlled by aliens (later revealed to be dolphins) who had made contact with the cold war superpowers?

Comment: @TheBeardyMan: 99% sure.  The immediate concession due to solving chess was a pretty core element.

Comment: "The only winning move is not to play."

Comment: After a few hours of searching, the best I could find was "The Immortal Game" by Poul Anderson.  It was published originally in in the February 1954 "The Magazine of Fantasy & Science Fiction" and later in "The Collected Short Works of Poul Anderson, Volume 1: Call Me Joe".  Unfortunately, after much searching, I cannot find the full text of this short story anywhere, so I cannot verify.

Comment: @PaulOmans - Poul Anderson's short story is the actual chess game 'The Immortal Game' (Anderssen v Keiseritzky) told from the perspective of the pieces. Probably not a match for this question. [Another story of note is Poul Anderson's "The Immortal Game" wherein the famous game of the same title played Anderssen and Kieseritsky is played out in and interesting venue.  The story is told from the perspective of the pieces and so has some interesting analysis of this famous historical game.](https://www.chess.com/blog/WyoKid/chess-stories)

Answer (score 5):

The story is "Last Ditch" by James P. Hogan, published in the December 1992 issue of *Analog*, and in his anthology *Rockets, Redheads & Revolution*.

The U.S. did not build a supercomputer in the story. The Soviets built one, capable of analyzing the entire game tree in a few hours, then challenged the U.S. to a single game, winner take all — as in, world domination. The U.S. simply made use of the best players and programs they could find — which would not have been enough, but in the event, they only needed one perfect move.